# regular expression to recognize 'x:...y:...z:...' in python

Tags: python, regex

There is a string with content in format of "x:...y:...z:...", '...' stands for any char **exclude ':'**, and can **contains any number of blank spaces**, I'm trying to split such string into ['x:...', 'y:...', 'z:...'], how can I do this in python?

example string:

```
'name: myname\n\naddress: myaddress1\nmyaddress2\n\nmyadress3\ncontact:mycontact\n'
```

what I want to get is:

```
['name: myname\n\n', 'address: myaddress1,\nmyadress2,\n\nmyadress3\n', 'contact:mycontact\n']
```

Comment: Where does the `myadress3` come from?

Comment: sorry, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`re.compile('\w+:[^:]*?(?=\w+:|$)')`

Meaning

1. Match one or more word character to a colon
2. Match everything not a colon lazily
3. Find either one or more word character and a colon or the end of the line

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jZ8dR5/1)

Answer (score 2):

Capturing *any* character except `:` would not be useful as it would include the newlines and `address`. It seems that your actual requirement is: **Match all text up until the beginning of the next line that contains a colon**. Here is one approach:

```
re.split("\n+(?=.*:)", s.strip())
```

The pattern means "a group of newlines followed by any text containing a colon". The input is stripped so that the final newline at the end will not be included in the final result item.

Comment: I removed my comment, spent a few minutes trying to add myaddress3 myself, realised after it does not exist!